# Need to check for nullptr when make_shared and make_unique is used?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

If I am creating a pointer using `make_shared` or `make_unique` do I ever have to check whether it is `nullptr` or not, like:

```
std::unique_ptr<class> p = std::make_unique<class>();
if (p == nullptr)
{
    ....
    ....
}
```

If you’re really running out of memory, `std::make_unique` will through an expection. So you will never get a null pointer from `std::make_unique`.
Is this correct ?

So there's no need to check for `nullptr` when you do `make_shared` and `make_unique`?

Comment: Cleaned up your post a bit :)

Comment: Note that you can check by `if (p)` as well.

Answer (score 13):

From cppreference on [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) (similar for `std::make_shared`):

> **Exceptions**
>
> May throw `std::bad_alloc` or any exception thrown by the constructor of `T`. If an exception is thrown, this function has no effect.

"This function has no effect" specifically means that it doesn't return anything because the exception handling mechanism kicks in. So yes, your assumption is right. Error handling in `std::make_unique` is done by exceptions, and the return value is never `nullptr`.

Comment: The “no effect” is to say that no garbage is left behind.  Of course if an exception is thrown (or rather emitted) the function doesn’t *return*.

Comment: So what on earth do we get in "p" if we are running out of memory?

Comment: @Shih-ChanHuang Nothing. When an exception is thrown, the control flow comes back to the closest `catch` block to handle the exception, while the stack and all its data, including `p` is cleared.